# How to set names in subclassed model? Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Is there any way I can give specific names to the output of a subclassed model?

Even though my output layers are called `layername1, layername2`, and I return the output as a `dict` with names `name1, name2`, the outputs still are called `output_1, output_2`.

### Model definition

```py
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.models import *
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import math as tm

class TestModel(Model):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.denselayer = Dense(33, activation='relu')
        self.outlayer1 = Dense(1, name='layername1')
        self.outlayer2 = Dense(1, name='layername2')
        
    def call(self, inputs):
        l_ = self.denselayer(inputs)
        out1 = self.outlayer1(l_)
        out2 = self.outlayer2(l_)
        return {'name1': out1, 'name2': out2}
    
m = TestModel()

x = tf.zeros((100,100,))
yhat = m(x)
y1 = tf.ones((100,1,))
y2 = 2*tf.ones((100,1,))

m.compile(optimizer='Adam', 
          #loss = {'layername1': 'mse', 'layername2': 'binary_crossentropy'},
          #loss_weights = {'layername1': 1, 'layername2': 1},
          loss = ['mse','binary_crossentropy']
          )
```

### This works:

```
m.fit(x, [y1, y2])
```

### This doesn't work:

```
dx = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x)
dy = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices({'name1': y1, 'name2': y2})
xy = tf.data.Dataset.zip((dx, dy)).batch(1)
m.fit(xy)
```

### This works:

```
dy = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices({'output_1': y1, 'output_2': y2})
xy = tf.data.Dataset.zip((dx, dy)).batch(1)
m.fit(xy)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "This doesn't work"? On the contrary, only the middle one works for me. If I call 
``out = m(x)
tf.print(out)``
I get the dictionary with the keys 'name1' and 'name2' as expected. The first one doesn't work because the model produces a dictionary and you're giving it an array. The third case doesn't match the names of the keys in the dictionary, and therefore cannot compute any gradients. What version of TensorFlow do you use? Make sure you have the current version.

Comment: Indeed, it works with 2.3. I was still working with 2.1.